# Assigning indicators based on observation quantile

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am working with a pandas DataFrame. I would like to assign a column indicator variable to 1 when a particular condition is met. I compute quantiles for particular groups. If the value is outside the quantile, I want to assign the column indicator variable to 1. For example, the following code prints the quantiles for each group:

```
df[df['LENGTH'] > 1].groupby(['CLIMATE', 'TEMP'])['LENGTH'].quantile(.95)]
```

Now for all observations in my dataframe which are larger than the grouped value I would like to set

```
df['INDICATOR'] = 1
```

I tried using the following if statement:

```
if df.groupby(['CLIMATE','BIN'])['LENGTH'] > df[df['LENGTH'] > 1].groupby(['CLIMATE','BIN'])['LENGTH'].quantile(.95):
    df['INDICATOR'] = 1
```

This gives me the error: "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (269,) (269,2)". Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) after your `groupby` to get an equivalently sized array.  `gt` is greater than.  `mul` is multiply.  I multiply by `1` to get the boolean results from `gt` to `0` or `1`.

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(labels=np.random.choice(list('abcde'), 100),
                       A=np.random.randn(100)))
```

I'd get the indicator like this

```
df.A.gt(df.groupby('labels').A.transform(pd.Series.quantile, q=.95)).mul(1)
```

---

In your case, I'd do

```
df['INDICATOR'] = df['LENGTH'].gt(df.groupby(['CLIMATE','BIN'])['LENGTH'] \
                                    .transform(pd.Series.quantile, q=.95)).mul(1)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was perfect.